# Не запускается код

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Раньше я использовал редактор, скачанный с оригинального сайта Python, соответственно все файлы данного расширения по умолчанию начали запускаться через него.

Недавно я скачал PyCharm(Установил туда пару модулей), когда я запускал в  самом редакторе(PyCharm), то всё работало прекрасно, но, когда я вышел и сохранил этот же файл, то он тоже по умолчанию должен запускаться через то приложения с оригинального сайта(Логично, что этот файл не запустился(С ошибкой импортирования нового модуля), ведь я похоже его установил только для PyCharm).

И вот проблема: как сделать так, чтобы он запускался как-то через PyCharm

Выше я открываю файл(Вы видите через что), но он просто запускает редактор, а нужно чтобы он выполнил код

Comment: Ваш файл "запускается" всегда с помощью интерпретатора, вызвать его можно через консоль (в случае linux: python3 file.py, тоже самое скорее всего будет и на windows) - это будет самый верный способ

Comment: А как его тогда добавлять, например, в автозагрузку?

Comment: В автозагрузку системы - в вашем случае - не знаю, чтобы поменять программу для открытия скорее всего нужно в свойствах посмотреть, там вроде бы что-то типа "открывать по умолчанию с..."

Comment: У меня, когда я ввожу в консоль python3 test.py: python не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: Ну, тут я уже бессилен) мой единственный совет в таком случае - сносите windows, ставьте linux, но есть и более нормальное решение - добавить в path интерпретатор, попариться со всеми вытекающими и так далее

Comment: Проблема была в том, что у меня не был установлен pip, а соответственно модуль, который я использовал, а в PyCharm я его установил похоже в виртуальной среде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выберете в качестве программы по умолчанию python.exe (который находится в папке с установленным питоном), для файлов с расширением .py - это решит вашу проблему автозапуска под PyCharm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если есть необходимость добавить запуск в автозагрузку или планировщик (чтобы запускалось по расписанию) можно создать батник, который запускает этот питоновский файл и работать уже с ним, что то типо:

```
echo "Запускаем файл test.py"
start "" "C:\test\test.py"
```

Если у вас код не запускается в самом PyCharm, то значит у вас там неправильно настроен интерпретатор, зайдите в настройки и выберите нужный вам интерпретатор
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в том, что я в PyCharm установил модуль pyautogui(например), но через этот python.exe файл с этим pyautogui не запускается с ошибкой не нахождения модуля